# If all elements of A are greater than x and all elements of B are smaller than a, det(A) is greater than det(B)

Tags: matrix, determinant

Let $A$ and $B$ are two $n \times n$ matrices and $x > 0$ is a scalar. If $\forall \; a \in A \;\;\; a > x$ and $\forall \; b \in B \;\;\; 0 \leq b \leq x$, and assume $A$ and $B$ are both positive semidefinite matrices.

Can we prove that:

$$det(A) > det(B)$$

Comment: Have you considered some examples?  Let $n=2,$ start with $x=1,$ let $B=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1},$ and see how much you can reduce the determinant of $A$ by populating it with values greater than $1.$

Comment: Maybe I am just tired but isn't $\alpha>x$ comparing a vector to a scalar?

Comment: @usεr11852 I believe "$a\in A$" and "$b\in B$" are intended to refer to individual components of the matrices $A$ and $B.$  More conventionally one might write "$A=(a_{ij})$ is an $n\times n$ matrix and $a_{ij}\gt x$ for all $i$ and $j,$" *etc.*

Comment: I was mostly thinking that $\alpha \in C(A)$ (column space) but hey ho! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**NO**.

Let $B=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}$ and $A=\pmatrix{2&1.9\\1.9&2}$.  Now calculate their determinants. And yes, both are positive semidefinite (even positive definite, with positive determinants).

(The value of $x$ can be taken as 1).

Comment: What is the value of $x$ for which all entries in your $A$ are _strictly larger_ than $x$ and all entries in $B$ are _at most_ $x$? Maybe take $B = \operatorname{diag}[x,x]$ for some $x \in (0,1)$?

Comment: @Dilip Sarwate: Example corrected